# Download files directly from the website member.bseindia.com

Tags: php, python

I am trying to download from this link [member.bseindia](https://member.bseindia.com/) from the folder

> CURRENCY > COMMON > DEC-2018 > 21-12-2018

these files:

> BFX_CO211218.csv
>  BFX_DP211218
>  BFX_SPD_CO211218.csv
>   BFX_SPD_CO211218.csv

This is a grid and I am not able to inject code into PHP script to download them directly.

I have tried using javascript auto-click but again I was stuck. I have even tried python mouse events, but they did not work.

This is sample code of file which I can download directly using the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$exists = remoteFileExists('https://www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ'.
    $date.$month2.$year2.'_CSV.ZIP'); 

$url='https://www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/EQ'.
    $date.$month2.$year2.'_CSV.ZIP';
if ($exists) {
    echo 'EQ'.$date.$month2.$year2.'_CSV.ZIP Downloaded'. "<br/>";
    $filename='EQ'.$date.$month2.$year2.'_CSV.ZIP';
    download($url,$filename);
} else {
    echo 'EQ'.$date.$month2.$year2.'_CSV.ZIP does not exists'. "<br/>";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to force it with the header, Not sure if this would work but it can give you ideas.

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$exists.'"');
readfile($exists);
```